# In an node.js + express app, how can you redirect a URL to remove a file extension from the previous site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htaccess, heroku, express

I am transitioning our site which is in a ASP environment and hosted on a Windows server.

The existing URL is

```
http://www.bruxzir.com/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/index.aspx
```

But I need it to be

```
http://www.bruxzir.com/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/
```

My `app.js` has this as the route

```
app.get('/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/', function(req, res){
  res.render('videos', {
    title: 'BruxZir Video Gallery'
  });
});
```

The new site will likely be hosted as a node.js app on heroku. Can I take care of this with an `.htaccess` ? if so, where would this be placed in an express app? and not all existing URLs have `index.aspx` only a few of them.

Comment: try to remove the last / from your defined route...  '/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown'

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to get this to work, but here's one with a little middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (/index\.aspx$/i.test(req.path)) {
    res.redirect(req.path.slice(0, req.path.length - 11));
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: what about query strings such as a=1&b=2 after the aspx extension

Comment: You can retain that if you like. It's parsed into an object available as `req.query` or you can use the `req.originalUrl` string.